# javascript regex - test is not a function

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate a password and if it is ok, it will keep in an array regular expression only once. When I run the script in the mozilla browser, I get the following error: 'seguridadPass [i]. Test is not a function'. I would also like to know how I can do to delete the array 'comprobaciones', those regex that have not been used. Thank you for your help.

[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/tk8n4/2/)

JAVSCRIPT

```
var compMay = /[A-ZÑ]/;
var compMin = /[a-zñ]/;
var compNum = /(?=.*\d)/;
var compCarEsp = /[!@#$%^&*(){}[\]<>¿¡?/|.:;_-]/;
var seguridadPass = []; 
seguridadPass.push(compMin,compMay,compNum,compCarEsp);
comprobaciones = [];

$('#write').keyup(function(){

var pass = $(this).val();
if(pass!=''){
    for(i=0;i<seguridadPass.length;i++){
        if(seguridadPass[i].test(pass)){
            //alert(seguridadPass[i]);
            for(j=0;j<comprobaciones.length;j++){
                if(comprobaciones[j]!=seguridadPass[i]){
                    comprobaciones.push(seguridadPass[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
else{
    comprobaciones.splice(0,comprobaciones.length);
    //comprobaciones = [];
}
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
seguridadPass.push(compMin,compMay,compNum,compCarEsp,8);
```

8 is not a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Your array mostly contains `RegExp` objects, but you've also pushed the number `8` to your array here:

```
seguridadPass.push(compMin,compMay,compNum,compCarEsp,8);
```

The `Number` type in JavaScript does not have a `test` method*. Remove the `8` and it should work:

```
seguridadPass.push(compMin,compMay,compNum,compCarEsp);
```

<sup>* Unless you provide one in `Number.prototype`.</sup>

Comment: Yes, I made a stupid mistake introducing 8. How can I check and delete elements in the array comprobaciones (regex) not in use?

Comment: @j_arab What do you mean by 'not in use'?

Comment: for example, if I decide to delete a character in the input, if it has been used a regex less than those stored in the array 'checks', delete that regex, if it has been stored previously

Comment: @j_arab If I understand what you want, it seems like the easiest solution would be to clear the entire array, re-run this entire script again.